# Can I assign FBA user a rights for the Administrator in SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata Service Application?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Can I assign FBA user a rights for the Administrator in SharePoint 2013 Managed Metadata Service Application ?

I have FBA configured in one of my web application and I have created a separate managed metadata service application for that.

Now I want one of the FBA user to be able to use manage metadata service from the site itself. To achieve this I want to assign that user Administrator rights. But when I am trying to search for the user in a People picker it is throwing error.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please let me know from where you are configuring admin exactly? I mean from Central Admin or from Site Settings > Term Store Management?

Comment: I am doing it from the central administration

Comment: Can you please try it from Site Settings > Term Store Management?